# SharePoint Site web content displays weird text

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

http://postimg.org/image/5lkd6szfn/

click the link for the funny text problem on SharePoint page content

ALL same problem on the following browsers -> IE, Chrome, and firefox
Our SharePoint Site works fine except for some users....
This SharePoint Site that displays funny text happens to some users only..
Related Symptoms on these problem...
symptom 1 -> Page does exist - after going back to home page and clicking back again to the subsite the pages will be displayed properly and the white page does not exist is gone...
symptom 2 -> after repeating the same testing home page to subsite.... subsite to home page.... the problem will now display the funny text like the image i have attached...
symptom 3 -> All InfoPath forms cannot be open keeps on loading like the endless circling gif

Initial Solution for some users: CHKDSK /R on the Command prompt and restart  = we did the checkdisk repair for the pc/laptop and the problem is gone...

But for some user the Checkdisk repair did not solve the problem....
We already did a repair also for the MS office... and Java Update but the problem was not solve.....

How start debugging from here...? and how to ask google about this problem also.... I can only describe it as a funny text or SharePoint Page Content is not displaying properly...
What do I search and find if I will investigate on the SharePoint logs.....?
If it is a javascript problem how do I repair it?

Answer (score 0):

The "funny text" you are seeing is compressed JavaScript. It appears to be one of the standard JavaScript files included with SharePoint. Please note, there is still a small amount of personal information in the image you provided. You may want to look closely at the image and redact additional parts for privacy reasons. The browser normally processes this code instead of displaying it to the user.

I seems to me that something on the affected computers is preventing proper JavaScript execution. My initial thought was a browser configuration issue, such as disabling JavaScript, however; this setting would consistently impact a single browser across all sites, not intermittently across all browsers on a single site.

Try starting Internet Explorer with no add ons to see if this eliminates the problem (Click Start -> All Programs -> Accessories -> System Tools, and then click Internet Explorer (No Add-ons)). If it does, you most likely have an add-on that is causing the problem. You could try enabling add-ons one at a time to see which is causing the problem.

My gut instinct tells me that these systems are infected with some type of malware. I would check the systems for malware including viruses by running a full virus and malware scan. A free tool called Malwarebytes is effective at detecting and removing malware. Malwarebytes is available at https://www.malwarebytes.org/. Another great tool is called HiJackThis which is available from http://sourceforge.net/projects/hjt/. Both of these tools can cause problems if used incorrectly so I recommend exercising caution when running them.